# Celery chain, how to run linked task locally

Tags: celery

I wrote Canva task, to chain task together that is an instance of celery task. 
Each task on the chain could have linked tasks and linked error tasks.

I need to be able to run the entire chain on the same worker (.apply on the chain). All are fine, expect that the linked tasks are not executed on the same worker.

So there any way to run linked task locally ?